# force the url showing a page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to force a URL in a jQuery Mobile page in the way it can show me what I want. For instance, I created a multiple-page-template in jQuery Mobile and when I click to a link it shows me the second page and in the URL there is the ID of my second page in the form: `#id-page`.

Now, since I have started to use this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).delegate('#info-button', 'click', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage($('#info'), {
        changeHash : false,
        role       : 'dialog'
    });
  });
</script>
```

I don't see the `#id-page` in the URL. Now I would put in the URL some name created from me. What can I do?

Is there a way to use the API jQuery Mobile `dataUrl`?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about the URL's `hash` changing when viewing different pages. Well right in your code you're telling the jQuery Mobile framework to not update the `hash` with this line:

```
changeHash : false,
```

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).delegate('#info-button', 'click', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage($('#info'));
  });
</script>
```

Notice that no options are being passed to the `$.mobile.changePage()` function, so it's using it's default settings.

Here is the documentation for `$.mobile.changePage()`, notice the different options you can set and what they mean: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/methods.html